# How to Create html table from associate array using php with for loop?

Tags: php, mysql

My associate array is as follows:

```
   <?php
     $marks = array( 
        "mohammad" => array (
           "physics" => 35,
           "maths" => 30,   
           "chemistry" => 39
        ),

        "qadir" => array (
           "physics" => 30,
           "maths" => 32,
           "chemistry" => 29
        ),

        "zara" => array (
           "physics" => 31,
           "maths" => 22,
           "chemistry" => 39
        )
     );      

     ?>
```

expected output as follows in table format using for loop:

```
<table border="1">
        <tr><td>Name </td><td>  physics</td><td> maths </td><td>chemistry</td></tr>
     <tr><td>mohammad</td><td>  35    </td><td>   30</td><td>        39</td></tr>
     <tr><td>qadir   </td><td>   30 </td><td>     32</td><td>        29</td></tr>
          <tr><td>zara   </td><td>   31   </td><td>   22     </td><td>    39</td></tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried with the `for()` loop since you expect the output in table format with this function?

Comment: @C0dekid he need for loop code

Comment: Actually, I need output as shown in table: <table border=1 width=auto>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th><th>physics</th><th>maths</th><th>chemistry</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>mohammad</td><td>35</td><td>30</td><td>39</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>qadir</td><td>30</td><td>32</td><td>29</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>zara</td><td>31</td><td>22</td><td>39</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

Answer (score 3):

Use `foreach()` on two levels, one for name and another one for marks with the table tags as string embedded with php `foreach()` loop.

Ex:

```
foreach($marks as $name => $mark)
{
    echo "<tr><td>".$name."</td>";
    foreach($mark as $key => $value)
    {
        echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested and it works How could you expecting: Use `foreach` inside `foreach`.

```
echo ' <table border=1 width=auto> <thead> <tr> <th>Name</th><th>physics</th><th>maths</th><th>chemistry</th‌​> </tr> </thead>';
echo '<tbody>  ';
foreach($marks as $key => $value)
{
   echo "<tr> <td>".$key."</td>";
   foreach($value as $strin)
   {
       echo '<td>'.$strin.'</td>';
   }
   echo '</tr> ';
  }
  echo '</tbody> </table>';
```

Comment: Yes, but what my aim was that, using foreach or for loop should read that array dynamically, person names, subject names and marks are all should display automatically. but i did not know that how to handle it, but still your approach is very much helpful. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($marks as $key => $value) {
 echo $key;
      foreach ($marks as $key => $value) {
       echo $value;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use foreach like

```
<th>
  <td>Name</td>
 <td>Physics</td>
 <td>math</td>
 <td>chemistry</td>
foreach($data as $array)
{
   echo "<tr><td>".$array['name']."</td>
           <td>".$array['physics']".</td>
         <td>".$array['math']".</td>
         <td>".$array['chemistry']".</td>
     </tr>";
  }
```

Comment: actually, first column will be name, second column will be physics marks, third column will have maths marks, and fourth column will have a chemistry marks dynamically without  writing  header names. is it possible using for loop dynamically?, thanks in advance.

Comment: I think there's no array index like `$array['name']`.